# What smtp do I use for email?

Tags: vb.net, email

I have a basic vb.net windows form application and is wondering how I would go about sending an email? I have no servers set up or anything like that, I was wondering if I could still send it without setting up all that stuff. This is the code I have now:

```
Private Sub sendEmail(ByVal golfersTable As DataTable)

    'create the mail message
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient()

    'set the addresses
    mail.From = New MailAddress("someone@gmail.com")
    mail.To.Add("someone@gmail.com")

    'set the content
    mail.Subject = "Golf Quotas"
    mail.Body = "Golfer Name" & "-----------------------------------------------" & row.Item("Average Quota")

    For Each row As DataRow In golfersTable.Rows

        mail.Body = row.Item("Golfer Name") & "---------------" & row.Item("Average Quota")
    Next
    'set the server

    SMTP.EnableSsl = True
    SMTP.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    SMTP.Port = "465"
    'SMTP.Send(mail)

    Try

        SMTP.Send(mail)

        MsgBox("Your Email has been sent sucessfully - Thank You")

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox("Message Failed To Send" & ex.ToString)

    End Try

End Sub
```

I have gotten nothing to work at all from everything that I have tried.... Idk what I'm doing wrong but it's not working. I tried a `nslookup www.gmail.com` in `cammand prompt` but it said that `domain not found` ?

Comment: If you have a Gmail account, you could use the Google SMTP server.

Comment: same as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954249/vb-net-email-not-sending

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a GMail account to send the emails then you can use Google's SMTP server, smtp.gmail.com.

More details here:
http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_SMTP_Settings.htm

Comment: So I would change `Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient()` to `Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")` instead? I'm having trouble figuring out where to put the pieces in the link you gave me

Comment: Yes, you can either specify the SMTP server host in the constructor arguments or via the Host property, here's the MSDN documentation for the SmtpClient class for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @DaveRead we already gave him this info, and he abandoned the previous question, check my comment above.